# Text to Pdf in R

Tags: r, csv, pdf, text

I have a text file (say **Dimension.txt**) with certain data in it,

I want to write a function in R that would convert this text file into a pdf file.

I googled a lot before I ended up here. There are a lot of places where people have asked as to how to convert a pdf file to text not the vice-versa.

Here is my code:

```
FunctionFun <- function(.csv)
{
  sink('Dimension.txt')
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)
  dimValue <- dim(csv)
  print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
  print(dimValue)
  return(dimValue)
  sink('Dimension.txt', append=TRUE)
}
```

When I run `FunctionFun("tips.csv")`, I get a text file as an output, which looks like:
[image]

Now, my task is to write a separate function that would convert **Dimension.txt** to **Dimension.pdf**.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You "googled a lot" but didn't see *anything* about `knitr` or `sweave`? That's unlikely or really bad googling. Read up on `knitr` and you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. It's unfortunate how people come to downvote a question, but there is nobody to give a productive answer. :)

Comment: Have you found any solution siince then?

Comment: Please see below the answer by @Rentrop, that is the accepted solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the following using `rmarkdown`

```
require(rmarkdown)
my_text <- readLines("YOUR PATH") 
cat(my_text, sep="  \n", file = "my_text.Rmd")
render("my_text.Rmd", pdf_document())
file.remove("my_text.Rmd") #cleanup
```

Which gives you a PDF document named `my_text.pdf` that looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: I already have a text file, I need to convert that into pdf. I don't understand what you tried to do with the answer.

Comment: You read in your text file what i simulated via `my_text <- c("Hello World", "Here we go")` you would do that via `readLines` then you apply formatting to it so each line goes into a new line via `cat(..., sep="  \n", ...)` and then you transform it. Did you at least try it?

Comment: Well, I tried with the method you said, then after I failed repeatedly, I tried using an alternative. I used the text2pdf.exe file, which worked well. And now, the solution you provided seems simpler and more elegant. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [textGrob](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.text.html) function?
Of course, this will lose all formatting. If you want to keep the orignal text formatting, you probably should not use R but one of the many pdf printers available online and a batch script.

Edit:

```
library(gridExtra)

toPdf=function(textfile="pathToFile", pdfpath="pathToPdf"){
 text=read.table(textfile, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 grb=textGrob(apply(text, 2, paste, collapse="\n"))
 pdf(pdfpath)
 grid.arrange(grb)
 dev.off()
}
```

Comment: So, you mean to say there is no way to do that?

Comment: Could you show an example of exactly what you want?

Comment: Ok, I'm not the best with R but I should be able to provide a workable and fast answer. There is probably a more elegant out there, but this should work. I will update in a second.

Comment: I need to keep an empty pdf file in the directory?

Comment: No, this creates a .pdf file.